# Unable to generate plot using matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I am a beginner to Python and experimenting with a plot. the script runs fine but plot does not show up.
the matplotlib and numpy libraries are installed.

````
import numpy as np
f= h5py.File('3DIMG_05JUN2021_0000_L3B_HEM_DLY.h5','r')


                                           #Studying the structure of the file by printing what HDF5 groups are present
for key in f.keys():
    print(key)                             #Names of the groups in HDF5 file.
# will print the variables in the file
                                           #Get the HDF5 group
ls=list(f.keys())
print("ls")
print(ls)
tsurf = f['HEM_DLY'][:]
print("tsurf")
print(tsurf)
tsurf1=np.squeeze(tsurf)
print(tsurf1.shape)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
im= plt.plot(tsurf1)
#plt.colorbar()
plt.imshow(im)```
Python version is 3 running on Ubuntu
````

Comment: Needs data. Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Always provide a complete [mre] with **code, data, errors, current output, and expected output**, as **[formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. If relevant, only plot images are okay.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to give you the exact answer without the dataset (please update the question with the dataset), but for sure, `plt.plot` does not return an object that can be plotted with `plt.imshow`

Try instead:

```
ax = plt.plot(tsurf1)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the error was on the final plot.Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f= h5py.File('/path','r')
ls=list(f.keys())

tsurf = f['your_key_str'][:]

tsurf1=np.squeeze(tsurf)

im= plt.plot(tsurf1)
plt.show(im) # <-- plt.show() NOT plt.imshow()
```